# See last order on specific product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi how to see last order of specific product in woocommerce?
EXEMPLE:

```
PRODUCT NAME 
PRICE 10 $ [ADD CART]

LAST ORDER
  DATE       QUT.  PRICE
10.10.2021    2     9$
10.12.2021    6     3$
10.01.2022    39    5$
```

EDIT: I would like to place it on the product page and as a second viewer user sees his latest product orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following function in your functions.php file

```
    function latest_order_by_product_id() {
        global $wpdb;
     
        // Select Product ID
        $product_id = 14;
    
        $orders_statuses = "'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold'";
        //Change get_row to get_col if you want all orders
        //Change DESC to ASC if we need reverse order
        $orders = $wpdb->get_row("
        SELECT DISTINCT woi.order_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim, 
        {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi,
        {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p WHERE  woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id AND woi.order_id = p.ID
        AND p.post_status IN ( $orders_statuses ) AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' ) AND woim.meta_value LIKE '$product_id' ORDER BY woi.order_item_id DESC");
    
        if($orders):
            $data = array();
            foreach($orders as $key => $order_id):
                $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
                if ( $order ):
                    $data[$key]['order_date'] = $order_date = $order->get_date_completed(); // Change depending on type of date you are looking for - get_date_created(), get_date_completed(), get_date_paid()
                    //Loop order items 
                    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ):
                        if($product_id == $item->get_product_id()):
                            $data[$key]['qty'] = $product_qty = $item->get_quantity();
                            //Choose which price you want to get
                            $data[$key]['price'] = $product_price = $item->get_total() + $item->get_total_tax(); // Discounted total with tax
                            //OR
                            //$product_price = $item->get_subtotal() + $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // NON discounted total with tax
                        endif;
                    endforeach;
                endif;
            endforeach;
        endif;
        
        if($data):
            $output = array();
            $output[] .='<table><thead><tr><th>LAST ORDER DATE</th><th>QTY</th><th>PRICE</th></tr></theead><tbody>';
            foreach($data as $order_data):
                //Change date format if needed
                $date = $order_data['order_date']->date("d.m.Y");
                $output[] .= '<tr><td>'.$date.'</td><td>'.$order_data['qty'].'</td><td>'.$order_data['price'].'</td></tr>';
            endforeach;
            $output[] .= '</tbody></table>';
        endif;
    
        echo sprintf('%s',implode($output));
    }
```

Call latest_order_by_product_id() where you need it. Result - https://prnt.sc/6AhgTPXFerBg

Example with shortcode. How to use **[lobpid product_id="35"]**

```
add_shortcode('lobpid','latest_order_by_product_id' );
function latest_order_by_product_id($attr) {
    global $wpdb;

    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'product_id' => '',
    ), $attr );

    // Select Product ID
    $product_id = $args['product_id'];

    //Skip the rest if we dont have product id defined
    if(empty($product_id)): echo 'there is no product id defined'; return; endif;

    $orders_statuses = "'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold'";
    //Change get_row to get_col if you want all orders
    //Change DESC to ASC if we need reverse order
    $orders = $wpdb->get_row("
    SELECT DISTINCT woi.order_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim, 
    {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi,
    {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p WHERE  woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id AND woi.order_id = p.ID
    AND p.post_status IN ( $orders_statuses ) AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' ) AND woim.meta_value LIKE '$product_id' ORDER BY woi.order_item_id DESC");


    //Skip the rest if we dont have orders 
    if(empty($orders)): echo 'no orders found'; return; endif;

    if($orders):
        $data = array();
        foreach($orders as $key => $order_id):
            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            if ( $order ):
                $data[$key]['order_date'] = $order_date = $order->get_date_completed(); // Change depending on type of date you are looking for - get_date_created(), get_date_completed(), get_date_paid()
                //Loop order items 
                foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ):
                    if($product_id == $item->get_product_id()):
                        $data[$key]['qty'] = $product_qty = $item->get_quantity();
                        //Choose which price you want to get
                        $data[$key]['price'] = $product_price = $item->get_total() + $item->get_total_tax(); // Discounted total with tax
                        //OR
                        //$product_price = $item->get_subtotal() + $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // NON discounted total with tax
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endif;
    
    if($data):
        $output = array();
        $output[] .='<table><thead><tr><th>LAST ORDER DATE</th><th>QTY</th><th>PRICE</th></tr></theead><tbody>';
        foreach($data as $order_data):
            //Change date format if needed
            $date = $order_data['order_date']->date("d.m.Y");
            $output[] .= '<tr><td>'.$date.'</td><td>'.$order_data['qty'].'</td><td>'.$order_data['price'].'</td></tr>';
        endforeach;
        $output[] .= '</tbody></table>';
    endif;

    echo sprintf('%s',implode($output));
}
```

Comment: yes but the $product_id is not automatic?

Comment: you can pass it as parameter ? latest_order_by_product_id($product_id) . U didnt mention where its going to be used and how you retrieve this product_id .

Comment: and how to active this ?

Comment: I would like to place it on the product page and as a second viewer user sees his latest product orders.

Comment: same this https://prnt.sc/10LfPcsP6SrW

Comment: news? for this ?

Comment: Use one of the woo hooks to load it where you want in your product or edit woo templates in your theme. To get product id you can set global $product which is an object and from there you can get $product_id = $product->get_id(); You should consider adding a check if user is logged in before that. As for the screenshot you can modify it and show any information about order if you want.

Comment: how to add by elementor ? can i use shortcode ?

Comment: You can add it as shortcode - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/ . As for elementor there are plenty of articles how to exetend with custom addon. Keep in mind to work as shortcode you need to either pass product id as param to shortcode or get id with global.

Comment: Can you edit for short code ? becouse me crash

Comment: I have added to the answer. But you should start reading wordpress codex and atleast understand how it works. Copy pasting codes its not the best idea if you are making website where people will use.